# jQuery + tablesorter + IE7 + large tables = hell

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I use jQuery and the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin extensively, but with tables of significant size (900-1200 rows), the plugin just grinds Internet Explorer (tried 7 and 8) to a halt.

Yes, I'd like to paginate (can't); yes, I'd like to tell everyone to use Chrome (can't), but I'm wondering if anyone has any other solutions. Perhaps a quicker table sorting plugin, or something I can try. I really don't want to do a server-side sort.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of IE's painfully slow JS engine!

Comment: What does happen in IE7? Is an error thrown? Does the browser crash? Or does it just take a long time? If so, how long?

Comment: Just grinds for about 60 seconds. Obviously it depends on the user's CPU. On Chrome it's lightning. I guess Mr. Pitts has it; I just thought I'd see if there were some other thoughts out there.

Comment: @Wells In Chrome it's lightning? As in ~100ms? That is a suspicious time difference. I tested tablesorter once and the difference was less then 10x slower. You can possibly improve the performance in IE if you re-factor the code. Can you post the code of one table row?

Comment: OK, lightning might have been an overstatement, but the difference is noticeable. The table in question has no code, each row just has seven columns of text. Then it's sorted just like:

 `var sort_opts = {widgets: ['zebra']};
 $("table.tablesorter").tablesorter(sort_opts);` - on a table with 1537 rows, the difference in IE7 and Chrome is huge

Comment: @Wells What does the zebra widget do? Paint even and odd rows differently? What happens with the performance of IE if you leave out that widget?

Comment: Couldn't you just simplify the equation in your topic to remove jQuery, tablesorter, large tables and the number 7?

Comment: I've run [this 2000-row test page](http://brian.peiris.name/so/4200562/) in IE7, running on XP inside a virtual PC, and tablesorter runs within 3 seconds every time, at least on my machine. Can you confirm? Do you have a specific example that causes the 60 second grind?

Answer (score 3):

How about client-side pagination? It's likely the speed hit comes from the DOM manipulation, not the sorting algorithm. So store the data in a javascript array, display only the first 20 items, and sort on the array and not on the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem with exactly the same tools.  The best you can do is try to make your HTML as clean as possible.  And, always remember to add a tfoot element BEFORE the tbody element.  This will help IE render the table faster:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>headers here</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>footers here</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>body here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Even if you don't need a footer, do it this way.  The only other advice I have would be to try some CSS tricks to either style or hide the table until the javascript is done loading.  Maybe start with an animated loading gif, and remove it when the javascript is done.

Answer (score -1):

IE 8 and Firefox cannot seem to handle large table dumps. They definitely croak at around 1000 lines. I have seen that with my application.

Chrome is literally superfast and will download 1000's of lines of HTML Table Output 100 times faster.

There is one problem with Chrome. After approximately 4,000 lines, the classes within my cell tables fail. The mouse hover which is connected to an action simply disappears and does not show up when the mouse is over a table cell.

While it takes 100 times as long to download a 5000-row table, the class links do not break in IE8 or Firefox. But who can afford to wait that long.

I think that I opened a bug with Chrome and never heard back.

Since my webpage runs in a closed environment, it is easy for me to force everyone to use Chrome.

This is where OPEN-SOURCE becomes an issue. There is no one to call for help!

Comment: I think the simple answer here is to use client-side or server-side pagination. No offense, but it is border-line ridiculous to expect a user to read through 5000 rows. I'm not surprised that Chrome breaks down and I'm not surprised that the Chrome devs would consider this a low-priority bug.